# What plant species generate the highest amount of bioelectricity?

Tags: botany, species, soil

I just want to ask which plant species produces a high amount of electricity. I'm very confused with the units that's why I don't know which species produce the highest amount of electricity. Also, can someone help me do differentiate each unit? It's just I don't have enough knowledge about it. By the way, the picture shows the species and produces power density through Plant Microbial Fuel Cell (PMFC)   Thank you...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details about using this site. Your question appears to be about converting between various units, which is off-topic as it is not about biology as defined in the [help]. Have you tried searching for "power density unit conversion"? In general, we expect you to make an effort to understand the site and learn what you can on your own before posting. Please do this and then delete or [edit] your post accordingly. ——— Also don't post [text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about biology as defined in the [help]. It is also poorly formatted (text as an image) and contains unreferenced material from an outside source.